# Extract Data from exported bookmark file

Tags: perl, extract

I have a ton of bookmarks I want to be able to pull out ones related to school and store them in a file.  I have been able to pull out the url, but I would like to pull out the title too.

Here is how the data is oriental stored in the exported bookmark file.

```
<DT><A HREF="https://google.com">Google</A>
```

I used this to get the url

```
perl -0ne 'print "$1\n" while (/a href=\"(.*?)\">.*?<\/a>/igs)' test.txt.bak |grep 'http://' > bak2
```

and it gave me

```
http://google.com
```

I would like to pull out the title and have a file like this

```
google
http://google.com
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You should not use RegEx to parse HTML. Prone to error and hard. Use HTML parser module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add another group and then print it out first.  That would give you the title and then add a \n break and place the first item on the second line. Such as:

```
perl -0ne 'print "$2\n$1\n" while (m{a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>}igs)' test.txt.bak |grep 'http://' > bak2
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  That was what I was looking for, but I didn't know how to get the title out.  If you don't mind could you break it down for me.  I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The () indicate a grouping {unless they are escaped with a \ for matching}.  So I added a set of around (.*?) after > and before <\a>. So then the items from each grouping are assigned to $1, $2 and so on from left to right.  To print out the title first (the second grouping), I add a $2 with a \n to get the title to print out first.  Hope that helps.  For more information and examples with explanations, I would search for regex tutorials and/or examples.

Answer (score 3):

As was mentioned you should use a module that parsing the HTML instead of relying on regex.

See my example below using [`HTML::Tree`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Tree)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use HTML::Tree;

die "USAGE: <program> <path/to/file> <query>\n" unless @ARGV == 2;

my ( $bmFile, $search ) = @ARGV;

my $tree  = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file($bmFile);
my @elems = $tree->look_down(
    _tag => 'a',
    sub {
        $_[0]->as_text() =~ /$search/i;
    }
);

printf "%s\n%s\n\n", $_->as_text(), $_->attr('href') for @elems;
```

Comment: I'm trying to run the code you provided to learn and see what it does, but it keeps on outputting the usage message and die.  Do I need to install anything special to run it.  I have tried running it like this ./program file and like this ./program file http: and like this ./program file www.google.com

Comment: @user2537388 apologies, fixed it in this line `my ($bmFile, $search) = @_;` replace `@_` with `@ARGV`